# How can I change DecimalFormat behavior based on input length?

Tags: java, format, decimal, number-formatting, decimalformat

I am using the following `DecimalFormat` pattern:

```
// Use ThreadLocal to ensure thread safety.
private static final ThreadLocal <NumberFormat> numberFormat =
  new ThreadLocal <NumberFormat>() {
    @Override protected NumberFormat initialValue() {
        return new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
    }
};
```

This performs the following conversions:

```
1    -> 1.00
1.1  -> 1.10
1.12 -> 1.12
```

I now have an additional requirement.

```
1.123  -> 1.123
1.1234 -> 1.123
```

That means that when

- there are fewer than two decimal places, I will "pad" to two decimal places.
- there are exactly two or three decimal places, I will do nothing.
- there are more than three decimal places, I will truncate to three decimal places.

Can I specify this behavior with the `DecimalFormat` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DecimalFormat("#,##0.00#")
```

Comment: That's is really an elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to change the *RoundingMode* of your `DecimalFormat` instance?

Calling `setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR)` should do the trick

See also [setRoundingMode(java.math.RoundingMode)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setRoundingMode%28java.math.RoundingMode%29)